# .Net KnockoutJS Link is Appending On Current URL

Tags: .net, knockout.js, hyperlink

I am using .net and knockoutjs. Via knockout I am trying to create a clickable link to an external URL. However when I do this it is trying to just append the href onto my current URL.

Any ideas on how to get this URL to navigate to an external URL?

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="web" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Website</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <!-- ko if: website() != "" && website() != undefined -->
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: website }" target="_blank"><span data-bind="text: website"></span></a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i know the external website URL? I just saw that giving http://www.learnveryeasily.blogspot.in/  (this contains http also before www)  is working in href. but giving www.learnveryeasily.blogspot.in/ is failing. 

A jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/38351/

Comment: The website URL's are all just going to be local high school URL's. All of the test ones I have in currently start with www.

Comment: ok but looks like html anchor itself (not knockout) is not navigating to the specified link if we dont specify http.

Comment: Yes, I believe it might be something with .net and not knockout, agreed.

Comment: hmm. give a try to append http if it can be done easily

Comment: it does look like if the URL is saved with the http:// it will work. I guess on validation I will just have to always make sure the http:// is present.

Comment: hmm yes. making sure http is present should work